# Info About The Caller of a Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, methods, stack-trace

All,

When debugging a web application in VS, I am noticing some weird behavior whereby a method that builds out some navigation is getting called twice.

I read [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/08/11/howtogetthecallingmethodandtype.aspx/) but not sure it's what I need or how to implement.

This is the method that I need caller info for:

The sender arg value is for a control which is the navigation builder:

```
{ASP.usercontrols_meganav_ascx}

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BuildMegaMenu(sender);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging, you can use the built-in [Visual Studio Call-Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx) window.
That way, you can view the function or procedure calls that are currently on the stack and find the offender.

On the **Debug** menu, select **Windows** and then click **Call Stack**.

For instance:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's a start. Would be nice if you could drill down more levels than this, like in Xcode

Comment: What do you mean by "drill down more levels than this"? Give me some example.